# The method RemoveAllViews in Android 2.2

Tags: android, view

I got confused by the Android SDK API.
   I invoked the GroupView.RemoveAllViews to clean all the child views, however, the UI does not refresh.
   By the way, I tried the RemoveViewAt(0) several times and A NullReference Exception occured, which means the sub view was removed but the UI does not change.
   Any help will be appreciated. Thank you so much.

This is part of the source code.

```
   private TableLayout contentTable;

   @Override
   protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
      contentTable = new TableLayout(this.getContext());
      for(int  i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i ++)
      {
         TableRaw tr = new  TableRaw(this.getContext());
         Button b = new Button(this.getContext());
         b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
               public void onClick(View v) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           Clean()
           }
         });
         tr.addView(b);
         contentTable.addView(tr);
      }
     super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
   }

   private void Clean()
   {
      contentTable.removeAllViews();
      this.invalidate();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invalidate your layout. use `invalidate()` method to your GroupView.

```
GroupView.invalidate()
```

---

From what I get from your comments.

I believe you have main activity as follow.

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
    testView yourviewGroup;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        yourviewGroup = (testView)findViewById(R.id.yourid);

        /**if you want to clean your viewgroup **/
        yourviewGroup.Clean();
        yourviewGroup.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: I used to try this.invalidate() and contentTable.invalidate(), but it does not work

Comment: I assume that u are putting this custom view (table layout) to your main activity. If so, invalidate need to call from ur main activity. Not from this Custom view file.

Comment: Not exactly. I generated the GroupView myself and used the view as a tag in xml file, saying <com.view.testView android:layout_width = ....../>. The testView extends GroupView. This is called in ViewGroup.

Comment: okay. So, what I am suggesting is you don't need to call **this.invalidate()** in your custom view file. 

\nYou need to issue invalidate() at your main activity that uses your xml file. For example, from your main activity, you call **Clean()** method first.Then u call **invalidate()** method.

Comment: THX. But I do not understand it because I could override the OnDraw() method and use invalidate() method in GroupView to refresh it.

Comment: Have you got MSN or sth like that? It is a long story to explain that. :)

Comment: oh. sorry. I am not allowed to use those during work hour in office. u can just comment or edit ur question to give more info. I do check up here time to time.

Comment: OK. Generally speaking, I need some custom views in an activity.These views extend ViewGroup. They can refresh themselves when the data update and they could react events to change the UI. The custom views could be composed in xml file mentioned before. In Android 3.0, it is called "Fragment" but in Android 2.2 there is nothing like that.

Comment: I finished part of them by override OnDraw, BroadCastReceiver,xml\res, reflect method, and background thread(or Service). But I was blocked by the RemoveAllViews method. :)

Comment: Just for thought, you can definitely use Fragement in 2.2 via “Android Compatibility package”. More detais on android dev blog. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html